# Having nosetests watch files from outside container and rerun tests inside container

Tags: python, docker, nose

How can I develop outside a docker container but still have nosetests watch my file changes and rerun my unit tests inside the container?

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install Python.
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install nose nose-watch mock && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data/test/src

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Here are my commands:

```
docker build -t="test” .
docker run -it -v ~/test/src:/data/test/src test
```

When I run `nosetests --with-watch` inside the container, everything works. However, if I make file changes outside the container (I want to develop outside the container), then nosetests won't detect the changes and rerun the tests. I thought a volume was supposed to share files from host to container...

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18246 - inotify does not work when mounting volumes to docker daemons running in virtual machines

Comment: ah man that sucks.. So you're saying this would work if I was on a linux box but since I'm on a mac and need a virtual machine, inotify won't work?